# CORS policy issue when consuming ASP NET Core 3.1 Web Api by Angular 8

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, cors

I have encountered issue with CORS policy when developing Angular 8, ASP NET Core Web Api web application. My angular app is running on http://localhost:4200
There is one service created for communication with Web Api. It looks as follows

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  apiUrl: string = "";
 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 
    this.apiUrl = 'https://localhost:44316';
  }

 
  login(Username: any, Password: any){  
    return this.http.post<Observable<ResultItem<AuthenticationResponse>>>(this.apiUrl + "/api/User/Authenticate", {Username: Username, Password: Password});
  }
 
}
```

Services is later called within component, but it is simply injected, and used with subscribe method.

```
 onLogin(){  
    this.authenticationService.login(this.loginFormValues.username.value, this.loginFormValues.password.value).subscribe(
       result => {}); 
  }
```

Web Api is running seperatly, on https://localhost:44316/
End point for the method called from Angular looks as follows:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserService userService;

    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    [HttpPost("Authenticate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate(AuthenticationModel model)
    {
        return Ok(await userService.Login(model));
    }
}
```

What I am most concerned about is my Startup file. So far, I have tried to change the CORS setting there, but with no successful results. Code of the Startup.cs file looks as follows.

Quick note:

Two lines of code within ConfigureServices method use some of my external functions, and their purpose is to:

- AddSubstracture:  registers all repositories as transients and registers DbContext.
- AddApplication: registers services which are one layer above repositories as transients

Startup.cs code looks as follows

```
public class Startup
{
    private IServiceCollection _services;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = environment;
        SportFacilityUnitSettings = configuration.Get<SportFacilityUnitSettings>();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public SportFacilityUnitSettings SportFacilityUnitSettings { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

        services.AddSubstructure(Configuration, Environment, SportFacilityUnitSettings);
        services.AddApplication(); 
        services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<User>, PasswordHasher<User>>();

        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);
         
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        }); 
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

       
        _services = services;
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors(
         options => options.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()
     );
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>(); 
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();  
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();  
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthorization();  
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers(); 
        });

    }
}
```

When I hit the login button, which purpose is to send the request, I receive following error in web browser console.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44316/api/User/Authenticate' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The weirdest thing about it, is when I debug it, and set up a breakpoint in Api layer, debugger hits it, then it enters the service layer and fails somewhere inside Authentication method .

Comment: if it hits the API when you debug, it is certainly not a CORS issue.

Comment: Chrome tends to show that error message even for issues that are not CORS related.

Comment: How do you send the bearer token for authentication from your angular application?

Comment: @G-Man You were right, Cors error was misleading and error was related to .AsNoTracking() option when updating some data on authentication. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS where your application is hosted and check if you have set the below information right.

**#Step 1** : IIS --> HTTP Response header]

[image: IIS HTTP Response header]

**#Step 2 :**  : Setting 4 fields in your API app hosted under IIS
[image: Set IIS values]

**#Step 3:** If the above 2 steps does not work, make sure you follow the msdn information to enable cors for your application
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

**Step 4 :**  : Investigate the header information you are using in your web API and if that's allowed under your IIS setting (as mentioned in Step 1)

**Step 5 :**  : Place a breakpoint in your authenticate method to see where and why its failing. You may get more clue from this error information as well.

**Step 6** : Try enabling CrossDomain to true from your front end.

**Step 7 :** Try enabling https for both the application (calling application and called application)