# .netcore 3.1 application breaks exactly after 1 min with CORS issue

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am running an application in .netcore 3.1 (WebAPI) as backend and Angular 9 as frontend.

I have a module in my application for Bulk User Upload through CSV file, and when we upload users a loader at FrontEnd starts, and after the successful upload it goes to next screen which says **"Upload Successful"**.

This module was working fine in my application when it was in .netcore 2.0 (a week ago)

But recently I have migrated my application to .netcore 3.1

The issue I am facing is, now when I try to upload Bulk Users, it breaks on front end **exactly after 1 minute** and **throws CORS issue** on console and stays on same screen. But the catch is in API level it is working fine and completes the loop and sends welcome emails to all the users added and they were able to login into the application.

The error in console and network tab:

[image]

[image]

Also, when I am trying to replicate the same issue on local it works fine and is not reproducible.

What I have tried on local to replicate the issue:

1. Ran Visual Studio in Release mode                                -- unable to replicate
2. Ran on my PC's IIS through localhost (like localhost:8045)       -- unable to replicate
3. Ran on my PC's IIS through IP address (x.x.x.87:8045)            -- unable to replicate

My hosting is on AWS server, which is throwing the CORS issue.

The changes I have tried to remove this CORS issue is:

1. Update the **web.config** with **requesttimeout**:

   <aspNetCore **requestTimeout="00:20:00"** processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" stdoutLogEnabled="false" />
2. Updated **Startup.cs**:

   ```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(CorsPolicy.ALLOW_ALL);
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
   ```

Updated **app.UseCors();** position as previously it was above **app.UseHttpsRedirection();**

3. Manually updated **connectiontimeout** of SP calls to 0. (I am using Dapper to connect with DB)

**My CORS policies:**

**a) Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(a => a.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(a => a.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc);
    CorsPolicy.ConfigureServices(services);
    ConfigureDependencyInjection(services);
}
```

**b) CorsPolicy.cs**

```
public class CorsPolicy
{
    public const string ALLOW_ALL = "AllowAll";

    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(AllowAll);
    }

    private static void AllowAll(CorsOptions options)
    {
        options.AddPolicy(ALLOW_ALL, builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    }
}
```

**c) web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add requestTimeout="00:20:00" name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Kindly suggest any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't debug images. Please post code.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624123/asp-net-core-2-error-handling-how-to-return-formatted-exception-details-in-http)

Comment: @John updated the images with code

Comment: And if I am not wrong, adding a middleware doesn't make sense as for exception logging, I already have code implemented. But in this case it does not log anything.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution.

1st thing, my chrome was pretty pathetic, it didn't show the 504 gateway timeout issue for the same request. As the server was idle for 1 minute. It breaks the loop and threw CORS error.

Sometimes, CORS errors are pretty misleading.

And for the solution, I have updated the idle timeout attribute in AWS server for that API, as previously it was 60 seconds. And it worked for me.

Thanks everyone for help.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! Thank you. I have been pulling my hair out for the last 2 days adding CORS headers & increasing server side timeouts trying to solve what I believed was a CORS issue and it was a similar problem to yourself with my AWS load balancer killing inflight requests after 60 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason for this error is having the below section in web.config. Comment the below code and set the option in IIS directly.

Try removing the below section from your web.config file

Also, take a look at :https://stackoverflow.com/a/64650214/14092386

```
<system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="<any_string_value>" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I have updated my web.config file as well and I do not have this code in my web.config.